# Как изменить событие onclick через jquery для элементов с определенным классом

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить через jquery к коду на страницу  location.reload();   для всех элементов с классом del_btn в событие onclick

Пример есть код:

```
<button type='button' onclick="cart.remove('{{ product.cart_id }}');" title='{{ button_remove }}' class='del_btn'></button>
```

Нужно добавить location.reload();  после ('{{ product.cart_id }}'); при этом не затрагивая сам product.cart_id

Чтобы было так:

```
<button type='button' onclick="cart.remove('{{ product.cart_id }}');location.reload();" title='{{ button_remove }}' class='del_btn'></button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю как-то так.

```js
var cart = { 
 remove: function (args) {
  console.log("remove " + args)
 } 
}

$(".del_btn").click(() => {cart.remove('{{ product.cart_id }}'); location.reload();})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type='button' onclick="cart.remove('{{ product.cart_id }}');" title='{{ button_remove1 }}' class='del_btn'></button>
<button type='button' onclick="cart.remove('{{ product.cart_id }}');" title='{{ button_remove2 }}' class='del_btn'></button>
```

Comment: Работает! БОЛЬШОЕ спасибо